# Three times the second integer less 4

Tags: grammar, semantics, syntactic-analysis

I am learning word problems for Quantitative reasoning GRE exams. English is not my first language and I wonder if the following expression is ambiguous in English:
"Three times the second integer less 4"
I interpreted that as 3(x-4), but the solution was 3x-4. Are there any conventions in English language? How do I know that "less 4" refers to the whole expression "three times the second integer" rather than to the expression "the second integer"?
I have not had this problem in non-mathematical literature since the relations were possible to be derived from the context, but here it does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Spoken English (i.e. - the *real* language) doesn't support brackets, but the intended sense *could* be indicated by stress/cadence. I writing, the ambiguity could be avoided by using brackets - but I think whoever decided to put this in a test thinking there was a single unambiguously "correct" answer is in the wrong job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convention is to write *3x-4* or *3(x-4)*. Mathematical notation was invented to reduce this kind of ambiguity.

However, the word *quantity* is often used to indicate parentheses. I would generally expect *3(x-4)* to be pronounced as:

> *three times the quantity, 'x' minus four*
>   *three times the quantity of the second integer minus four*

If the word *quantity* wasn't present, the phrase is ambiguous, but I would assume the phrase should be interpreted as a sequence of symbols precisely as stated, as though no parentheses are present, *3·x-4*. In which case, the conventional order of operations takes precedence and multiplication should be performed first.

Comment: I often hear this same convention used, sometimes without the "the": _Three times quantity x minus four_.

Comment: @J.R. I've also heard *x minus four quantity times three*. Ultimately, this doesn't help reduce ambiguity that much.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of any other indication, I would take it in the sequence given:
(1) "Three times the second integer", then
(2) "less 4".
That would also be the mathematical sequence in the absence of brackets.

While I agree that there is an ambiguity, there is nothing to suggest doing the calculation in anything other than the specified sequence.